# Pros/Cons of using operator overloading (new/delete) to implement Singleton

Tags: c++

I was brushing up my C++ knowledge and I chose implementing singleton to be starting point. Just I didn't want to implement the classic private constructor & `static getInstance` method way of doing it.

So here is a Rube Goldberg way,

```
class Singleton : public IDestroy {
    static Singleton* iS; // Singleton instance
    static int count; // number of undeleted objects

    int a;

    public:
    Singleton(int A = 0) {
        if (!iS) {
            a = A;
            iS = this;
        }
        count++;
    }

    void destroy() {delete this;} // way to destroy HeapOnly

    int get() {
        return a;
    }

    static void* operator new(std::size_t size);
    static void operator delete(void* ptr);
    protected:
    // Ensuring construction of HeapOnly objects
    // If object created on stack, there is no control of new operator
    ~Singleton() {
        count--;
        std::cout << "Destroyed, remaining :" << count << std::endl;
    }
};

void* Singleton::operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    if (iS)
        return iS;
    else
        return ::operator new(size);
}

void Singleton::operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    if (!count)
    {
        ::operator delete(ptr);
        iS = 0;
        std::cout << "Cleared memory" << std::endl;
    }
}

Singleton* Singleton::iS = 0;
int Singleton::count = 0;
```

And to work well with shared_ptr:

```
class IDestroy
{
    public:
        virtual void destroy() = 0;
};

class HeapOnlyDestroyer {
    public:
        void operator()(IDestroy* s) {
            s->destroy();
        }
};
```

Now, I can use the same object like:

```
a = new Singleton(1);
..
a->destroy();
```

or

```
shared_ptr<Singleton> s(new Singleton(1), HeapOnlyDestroyer());
```

I wanted to know if there are any problems in this approach, also its pros/cons over the classic way of using `static getInstance` method.

Cons:

1. It is confusing that object is not actually being created with new
2. Inheritance is possible that will create mess to maintain singleton functionality (could this be turned into a feature?)

Comment: Con: It´s confusing nonsense. A `new` which doesn´t allocate something "new" is like a `+` for division.

Comment: Yes, but it could be a way to hide the fact that class is singleton (from say, a  library user). As singleton should be used when it is absolutely necessary to ensure single owner of a resource (a hardware maybe). In my case I dont want user to know anything about it.

Comment: @SagarPadhye The user *will* know about it from the strange side effect that "creating" a seemingly new instance affects all other instances. It's less confusing to be explicit about global state.

Comment: Any ideas as, How this can help if the singleton class and some other classes (that are not singleton) implement same interface & I want to use factory like patterns? How this will affect in inheritance? I am convinced that it creates confusion about object state, but I wanted to know more cons.

Comment: Well, at least if Singleton is your starting point, it can only get better!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what is the **pro** of **this** implementation?

> Just I didn't want to implement the classic private constructor[...]

Why not?
Why not following the least surprise rule and using the Meyers Singleton?

e.g:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/4/

```
class Log {
public:
  static Log& Instance() {
    static Log theLog;
    return theLog;
}
  void Write(char const *logline);
  bool SaveTo(char const *filename);
private:
  Log();          // ctor is hidden
  Log(Log const&);      // copy ctor is hidden
  Log& operator=(Log const&);  // assign op is hidden

  static std::list<std::string> m_data;
};
```

P.S.: Off the records, my first implementation of "singleton" was like this. After explaining the code to a college for half an hour, suddenly he asked: "Is it a singleton what you are trying to achieve?" I had to confess, I had no idea at that time, what a singleton was.

Comment: Having the least surprising implementation is always the way to go, but every little feature available in C++ could be useful in most surprising way. This is just an attempt to explore a possibility in theory.